# Solarized colors inside terminal emacs

Tags: colors, emacs, terminal

I trying to setup the solarized color scheme for Emacs running in terminal mode. I use 
https://github.com/bbatsov/solarized-emacs.git 's `solarized-dark` theme. However while this works for *desktop windows* the colors are modified when running in terminal mode `emacs -nw`:

[image]

The color is a dark blue while the standard background for solarized dark
is dark and geenish:

[image]

The standard background color `#002b36` is defined [here](https://github.com/bbatsov/solarized-emacs/blob/87d4758e7ecc8ed873f3326e4f8b185fd2b9da0a/solarized.el#L147). I tried to change it but there seem to be an interpolation layer inside Emacs that changes it to blue unless I change it to something more different like black.
Does anyone know howto configure Emacs to support more color shades?
I'm running inside `Kconsole` but can see the same behaviour in `gnome-terminal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/sellout/emacs-color-theme-solarized handles solarized dark theme colors in terminal mode.

Answer (score 2):

By default terminal works in 16 colors mode. You have to set environment variable TERM:

```
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

I'm using zsh, so I put this line in my `~/.zshrc` file.

Comment: The TERM variable is already set to ```xterm-256color``` in ```Konsole``` as well as ```gnome-terminal```.  I also upgraded emacs to 26.1 but still the same. In the meantime I found this issue on the issue tracker: https://github.com/bbatsov/solarized-emacs/issues/18 it seems to be open for quite some time. It seems an issue that is undecided to be fixed. It seems that ```TERM=xterm-24bits``` would fix the issue but that definition is not supported in tinfo of Ubuntu 18.10.